# JavaScript only code returning "Cannot read properties of undefined" when object property should be defined

Tags: javascript

I have been trying to figure this out for two hours. The object has the all of the details there, it should be able to find those details once called. But it isn't. Thank you for any help.

```
if (localStorage.getItem("contactDetails")){
    
    println("Name: " + contact.firstName);
}

else {
    var firstNameVar = prompt("What is your desired first name to log?");
    var lastNameVar = prompt("What is your desired last name to log?");
    var phoneNumVar = prompt("What is your desired phone number to log?");
    
    var contact = {
        firstName: firstNameVar,
        lastName: lastNameVar,
        phoneNum: phoneNumVar
    }
    
    localStorage.setItem("contactDetails", JSON.stringify(contact));
}
```

[image: The error]

I have tried changing between localStorage and directly calling it, I have tried using the object["item"] method rather than just object.item, and a few other things.

**EDIT: Going to have to come back to this one. I have tried every single suggestion and it still is not working. My brain is extremely fried from 3 hours of one problem. This is the entire code, there is no more code than this. I'll get back at another time for this. Thank you for your patience!**

Comment: No where in your code do you actually give `contact` a value. ... How is `localStorage.getItem("contactDetails")` supposed to know to give it to `contact`?

Comment: Shouldn't contact.firstName have its value from the prompt variable? That was my train of thought.

Comment: I'm not talking about your `else`, i'm talking about the 1st `if` you show. That's where the error is. That's the line that is high lighted in the screen shot you show. In it, you don't define what `contact` is.

Comment: I think I see the issue. Because contact is being defined in the else statement that only runs on the first load and after you clear localstorage cache, next time I run the site it is only running the if part of the if-else statement. So it doesn't know what to do with the contact object. Is that correct?

Comment: It does know what to do it: it returns a value. *You* are not assigning that value anywhere.

Comment: @ItsCat03 Define `contact` outside `if` statement. Then use in both `if` and `else`. Also, I do not recommend using `var`. Use `let` instead.

Comment: @OP - May I please understand the impact of: `if (localStorage.getItem("contactDetails"))` - is the expression between the outer `(` and `)` going to return a `boolean`?

Comment: @jsN00b it returns either a string value or `null` (or possibly `undefined`). Both the empty values will test as `false` in the `if` statement, but that's really where the problem is here. The code should be **saving** the result of the local storage lookup into the `contact` variable, and then testing the variable in the `if` statement.

Comment: @Pointy - indeed, that's where I was heading towards. It may return `truthy` or `falsy` - but if it was `truthy` then that result (be it a string or an array or an object) needs to be kept-safe in order to use in the next `println` line.

Comment: Why did you hesitate to "heading towards" that way when it's the highlighted line in your debugger?

Comment: Have you declared contact variable before ? I think , contact is being hoisted to be undefined because of which you are getting the error . Share the entire code which will make debugging more easier.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
let contact = localStorage.getItem("contactDetails")
if (!!contact){
    
    println("Name: " + contact.firstName);
}

else {
    let firstNameVar = prompt("What is your desired first name to log?");
    let lastNameVar = prompt("What is your desired last name to log?");
    let phoneNumVar = prompt("What is your desired phone number to log?");
    
    contact = {
        firstName: firstNameVar,
        lastName: lastNameVar,
        phoneNum: phoneNumVar
    }
    
    localStorage.setItem("contactDetails", JSON.stringify(contact));
}
```

PS : Avoid using **var** , instead use **let** or **const** .

Reason why I insist not to use var instead use let or const is as follows :

This code will print **Global Variable** even though **globalVar** is defined inside **if** statement because of **scoping property** of **var** .

```js
if(true){
  var globalVar = "Global Variable"
}

console.log(globalVar);
```

This code will give you an **error** , as you have not defined scopedLet outside if and still trying to access that variable.

```js
if(true){
  let scopedLet = "Scoped Let variable"
}

console.log(scopedLet);
```

Same is the case with **const**.

```js
if(true){
  const scopedConst = "Scoped const variable"
}

console.log(scopedConst)
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got two problems going on here.

One problem is that when you call `localStorage.setItem("contactDetails", JSON.stringify(contact));`, you are storing a string, so when you call `localStorage.getItem("contactDetails")` you get a string back. To fix this you need to wrap it in a JSON.parse(), so it looks something like this: `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("contactDetails"))`.

The second problem is that you are calling contact.firstName before you define the variable contact. To fix this you need to change your if statement to look like this: `if (localStorage.getItem("contactDetails")){ let contact = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("contactDetails")) println("Name: " + contact.firstName); }`

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Right on `JSON.parse` but there's no need to fetch "contactDetails" twice. Also, `contact` should initially be declared outside the if/else so both scopes have it, if that is the OP's goal.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues in your code that I have noticed.

---

### Issue #1

You are asking for the value of `contact.firstName` before it is defined.

To fix this, you need to change the inside of the `if` statement to the code below.

```js
let t = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("contactDetails"))
console.log("Name: " + contact.firstName);
```

*Note: I changed the syntax a little as it didn't look like JavaScript.*

### Issue #2

When you call `JSON.stringify()` on your JSON and store it in `localStorage`, you are storing it in a `string`. However, when you are getting the key, you are not parsing the JSON. To change it back, you need to use the code below when getting the key.

```js
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("contactDetails"));\
```

Answer (score -1):

It says undefined meaning the variable contact.firstName is not defined

u need to define first the object `contact` before your `if else`

```
let contact = {
 firstName = "john"
}
```

in here u have `contact.firstName`

and it will print `"john"`

Comment: The variable `contact` is not defined. The error means that a property can not be read from `undefined`.

Comment: The problem with that is then I cannot use a prompt to determine the value of firstName. And if I use a variable in that context I'm back to the original code's functionality.

Comment: ok, i think what you need is u need to create another localstorage for contact

let contact = {
  firstName : "john"
}

localStorage.setItem("contact",contact)

this is inside of your else statement

and u can call it as localStorage.getItem("contact").firstName